# WebRTC Support for Safari 11 Still Broken

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit, webrtc, ios11

I've been anxiously awaiting the release of Safari 11 on OS-X and iOS 11. Now that they're finally here, I can use Safari to record audio data from the microphone -- except that the long-promised support doesn't actually work.

I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 with Safari Version 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7). The following demos all fail with errors:

- https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/ -- Unhandled Promise Rejection: [object DOMError]
- https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/msr/audio-recorder.html -- media error -- TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating new Recorder(mediaStream))
- https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/webaudio-input/ -- Failed to get access to local media. Error: ReferenceError
- I've been able to code my own demos that work in FF/Chrome/Edge but capture only "empty" audio in Safari 11 while displaying no errors.

Can anyone out there confirm this behavior? First off, I need to know if I'm alone in seeing WebRTC completely broken in Safari 11.

Next up is Safari 11 in iOS. This is much harder for me to test. It seems like all the demos above are also broken on iOS. Safari 11 on iOS Simulator in XCode doesn't even seem to support WebRTC at all whereas actual Safari 11 on iOS reports to the browser that it's supported but, like desktop, it doesn't actually work.

Does anyone know what in the world is going on? As far as I can tell, the Safari 11 that was just pushed out to iOS 11 and Sierra not only doesn't support audio recording, but MUCH worse, passes the getUserMedia feature detection code implying audio can be captured (but it never actually works).

I'm curious if upgrading to High Sierra fixes anything but I don't want to try because even if it works there, I need access to a broken state to try and come up with some way to work around the busted feature detection.

I need to get a handle on this but it's proving difficult because the only documentation online says that "Safari 11 supports the audio portions of WebRTC" which I cannot replicate anywhere on either my phone or desktop.

Any help or confirmation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The webaudio-input demo fails due to the lack of an unprefixed AudioContext. Try if
`window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;`

fixes things

Also see [this issue](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/929) about some hacks required to make things work.

Comment: I actually heard back from someone at Apple who clarified a couple things for me. The big thing I wasn't understanding is that Safari 11 apparently only supports audio streaming, but not audio capture. So when you attempt to actually capture an audio stream locally you apparently either get an error or (as I was seeing) an empty stream.

I really hope there's a fix to this or a workaround because I need capture, not streaming.

Comment: recordrtc used to implement its own MediaRecorder API before MediaRecorder was added to Chrome, probably it is going to add another hack for safari. Check the github repository, there are a couple of issues.